# Does GPU act as an extra processor to share/help reducing the computational load from CPU when doing non-graphics RAM/compute intensive tasks?

Tags: graphics-cards, memory, nvidia

Apart from high-res, high-frame gaming/other graphics related stuff there are some tasks which are felt either memory/RAM or CPU intensive, some of which are:

1. Browsing with 10-20 open tabs.
2. Dealing with very large Excel files.
3. Compiling the code for large projects/Extensive use of Build tools.
4. Using IDEs or development tools like Android Studio, Visual Studio.
5. Using VirtualBox/Docker on your computer.
6. Extensive Multitasking and using many of the heavy processes which include but are not limited to the above ones.

Does GPU helps reduce the computational burden from the CPU in doing such tasks, thus giving better overall performance to the end user? I've read that the main use of GPU lies in assisting CPU in doing graphics intensive tasks like gaming, 3D design and modelling and multimedia editing software that are similar to those provided by Adobe?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from GPU tasks, it can also handle anything OpenCL also known as CUDA cores or stream processors.

Tasks like Bitcoin mining.

Web pages has tons of graphics so it does accelerate the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU is a Graphics Processing Unit. From here, you can check what the gpu is approximately doing. In web browsing the gpu can help decoding video's, but the CPU (Central Processing Unit) gives tasks to the gpu and if it doesn't, the gpu will be silent and just draw pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The GPU is working **With** the CPU. While intense graphicing when the CPU is overloaded or is not detected/compatible, the GPU activates.
But mostly the GPU is just working on shaders and the CPU the scripts.